# How do we check whether a media recorder is already active before starting a new recording?

Tags: android

Problem that I am facing is that my application crashes during recording (Media Recorder)   when another recording is active (such as default media recorder). So is there any way to handle this without catching it in  `IllegalStateException`? If i use `IllegalStateException` the recorder audio gets corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

There is no method on MediaRecorder like isActive() or something (I think it where good to have one, but....). So a good way is to set a boolean inside Your app and everytime you start recording, set this boolean to true. By stop recording, set this boolean to false.

Comment: But in my case,first Iam running the device default recorder and while it is running Iam just starting my media recoder and my application crashes.So how will I handle such a situation

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out a solution,
I was not able to get a method or a listener for MediaRecorder such as isactive() or so......... So what I did was record a dummy audio while another recorder is active(such as a default recorder in android device) at that time an IllegalException is being catched and a flag is set(flag=1),based on the flag value ie if flag is 0 then our original recording is started else show a AlertDialog that a recorder is active, this checking is done each time recording is started.

Answer (score -1):

To check recording status there is a property called `state`

```
var PREFIX_MEDIA_RECORDER = new MediaRecorder(stream);

if( PREFIX_MEDIA_RECORDER.state == 'recording' ){
    alert("Recording already started")
}else{
    alert("Recording Not started yet")
}
```

Comment: This question refers to Android's `MediaRecorder`, not the one available on browsers